# Angular2 Vs combination of Jquery, JsRender and JSView

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jsrender, jsviews

I am developing single page application which can be used on all the devices Phone, tablets (using apache Cordova) and desktop. Initially I started with Angular2 since it has component based development model (for code reusability), two way databindng, separation of concerns, dependency injection and efficient DOM manipulation. After developing it for some time, I was frustrated mainly because it has a lot of learning curve, it requires lot of tooling support for development (nodejs, node lite development server, polyfills, systemjs, observables, typescripts etc.), obscure error messages, lack of adequate documentation (since it is in beta). Also one has to write lot of code to accomplish simple task such as setting the focus in the textbox.

Finally I decided to go with Jquery 2.0. Since Jquery is lacking templating  support and two way data binding, I am using JSRender and JSViews. JSRender and JSView will help to reduce the amount of code that I need to write. I believe I  certainly can write clean code if I separate logic for services and repositories into separate files even using Jquery. So question is

1. What benefits I am going to lose if I use combination of JQuery, JSRender and JSView over Angular2. I know dependency injection feature is one of them.
2. Any other popular library with minimum learning curve for templating and two way data binding which can be used with Jquery?

Answer (score 1):

> *What benefits I am going to lose if I use combination of JQuery, JSRender and JSView over Angular2. I know dependency injection feature is one of them.*

I guess you have answered it in the question. Although i am not aware of JSRender/JSView so i will not comment on it. jQuery is good for DOM and ajax based operation, as i have used it and i like it.

> *Any other popular library with minimum learning curve for templating and two way data binding which can be used with Jquery?*

For this you can look into [ReactJs](https://facebook.github.io/react/). It does have <del>minimum</del><sup>1</sup> ← learning curve. These are some of the benefits of ReactJs:

1. Simple.
2. Declarative
3. Build Composable Components
4. Interactivity and Dynamic UIs
5. Multiple Components
6. Reusable Components
7. Transferring Props
8. Forms
9. Working With the Browser
10. Refs to Components
11. Tooling Integration
12. Add-Ons
     12.1 Animation
     12.2 Two-Way Binding Helpers
     12.3 Test Utilities
     12.4 Cloning Elements
     12.5 Keyed Fragments
     12.6 Immutability Helpers
     12.7 PureRenderMixin
     12.8 Performance Tools
     12.9 Shallow Compare

You can [get more details about these here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/why-react.html).

<sub>*1. This does have a learning curve but can't say min or max. That actually depends on author who is using this library.*</sub>

Comment: Thanks for providing ReactJS option. Appreciate if you share any other option in Jquery ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

I use the combination of jQuery + jsView in a production sites.I have worked with Angular and ReactJS and both require a lot of other files and libs and are over complicated. With jQuery + jsView you can simply do everything.